# Rolling update with shared folders/files Docker

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, production-environment, volumes, mounted-volumes

I'm looking for a way to share files/folders between Docker containers. Especially sharing a file gives me issues. I want to use Docker in production with docker-compose and use a deployment technic that gives me zero downtime (like green/blue or something else).

What I have so far, is to deploy the new source code by checking out git source first. I keep the old container running, until the new one is up. Then I stop the old one and remove it.

The problem I'm running into with shared files is that Docker doesn't lock files. So when two containers with the same application are up and writing the same file shared_database.db this causes data corruption.

Folder structure from root looks like this:

```
/packages (git source)
/www (git source)
/shared_database.db (file I want to share across different deployments)
/www/public/files (folder i want to share across different deployments)
```

I've tried:

1. symlinks; unfortunately Docker doesn't support symlinks
2. mounting shared files/folders within the docker-compose file under volumes section, but since Docker doesn't lock files this causes data corruption

If I need to make myself more clear or need to provide more info i'd be happy to. Let me know.

Comment: Maybe you want to try flock, see: ``man flock``

Comment: This is a good reason to use a relational database server that you can access over the network (both PostgreSQL and MySQL are common choices); that will manage concurrent access for you.  An architecture based on shared files will also be difficult to scale as you move to a multi-host system (you've tagged this with Swarm).

Comment: I did indeed tag it with swarm as I've also tried to see if swarm had any solutions for sharing files/folders, but I couldnt find any. In the future I might also need to scale. Guess I would need to use a MySQL database then instead of a lightsql. And when it comes to shared public folders/files I might need to use a CDN.